# Smack multi user chat list of online users

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, multiuserchat

I'm using the account administrator to login into my openfire XMPP server, from my third party server.

I need to discover the available users into specific multi-user-chat. For "available" I mean all the users ONLINE in the room.

I know that the one way is to connect to room and listen for users presence, but for my purpose I need to get the complete list on the fly.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the ServiceDiscovery for that. Here is a example:

```
      // Obtain the ServiceDiscoveryManager associated with my Connection
      ServiceDiscoveryManager discoManager = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

      // Get the items of a given XMPP entity
      // This example gets the items associated with online catalog service
      DiscoverItems discoItems = discoManager.discoverItems("plays.shakespeare.lit");

      // Get the discovered items of the queried XMPP entity
      Iterator it = discoItems.getItems();
      // Display the items of the remote XMPP entity
      while (it.hasNext()) {
          DiscoverItems.Item item = (DiscoverItems.Item) it.next();
          System.out.println(item.getEntityID());
          System.out.println(item.getNode());
          System.out.println(item.getName());
      }
```

Comment: Please, keep in mind that this will only go halfway there: it will list the chat rooms, it will list the users in each chat, but it won't list the *real* JIDs of the users.